# DisplayPort with Targus 2k Dock and Dell E6230

Tags: 16.04, graphics, displayport, displaylink

I am using a Targus 2k dock with my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.  After installing the displayport drivers the targus dock was able to work with my laptop and connect me to my two external monitors.  The problem is that one of my external monitors is rotated 90 degrees.  When I go into system settings, the monitor I want to change only has "Normal" under rotation.  My laptop, however, has all rotations available.  I then tried to use various commands with xrandr and got:

```
xrandr: output --- cannot use rotation "right" reflection" none
```

I have read this means that the drivers I am using doesnt support rotation.  Is there a way I can change this?  Or is it something else I need to do to allow rotation?

My output for inxi -xG is:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       bus-ID: 00:02.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1366x768@60.22hz
       GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Targus 2K](http://targus.com/us/2k-universal-docking-station) appears to be a DisplayLink device, searching a bit brought me to [this](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/641668-known-issues-with-displaylink-ubuntu-support) page with the following statement:

> - Rotation is not supported due to missing functionality in the generic modesetting driver

It's not clear to me when this article was written and if it's still up to date, I have to guess it is still correct and there is nothing that can be done about that.